# Selenium test in tablet viewport does not open menu on hamburger button click

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written tests using Selenium WebDriver and I have problems with opening menu bar in tablet view.

The HTML code for section:

```
<div class="hidden-xs col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-6 search_base">
    <div class="assortment user_data_inner hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <a href="/c/N00"><input class="btn-black" type="button" value="Shop"></a>
    </div>
<div id="js-mobile-nav-icon" class="sticky-hambruger-container assortment user_data_inner hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <a class="sticky-burger-a">
        <div class="sticky-hamburger-clickable">
            <div class="sticky-header-hamburger"></div>
            <div class="sticky-header-hamburger"></div>
            <div class="sticky-header-hamburger"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div> 
</div>
```

On mobile i use find element By.cssSelector and it works fine, the menu opens with name Products and test passes.

```
public void openHam() throws Exception {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.title = 'Opening hamburger...'");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#js-mobile-nav-icon")));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#js-mobile-nav-icon")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("body > div.mobilenav-cover.js-mobnav-close > div > div.mobilenav-cat-header.font-bold"))).getText().equals("Products");
}
```

But on tablet the same code does not work.

I get error message

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector:
>
> ## js-mobile-nav-icon (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

If i remove `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#js-mobile-nav-icon")));`

I get error

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException

I also tried to modify the code to

```
    public void openHam() throws Exception {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.title = 'Opening hamburger...'");
        WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#js-mobile-nav-icon"));
        String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, elem);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#js-mobile-nav-icon")));
        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#js-mobile-nav-icon")));
        actions.perform();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#js-mobile-nav-icon")).click();
     }
```

But i haven't found a solution. So guys any advices?

Comment: The message says the element can not be found. can you validate that the element is really in the view? Do you have video playback or the device so you can validate the element is visible

Comment: Yes the element is in the viewport and i found a working solution to click that button